# How to get Selected item in a Spinner to show a TextView

Tags: android

Hey I was wondering if someone could help me edit my code to show a Text View rather than a class. Thanks for any help.

Current Code:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    String classSpot = classes[pos];
    try {
        Class nextClass = Class.forName("com.example.famouspeople." + classSpot);
        final Context context = this;
        Intent intent = new Intent(context,nextClass);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you want? if you select item from spinner so, update text in textview?

Comment: @sajmon_d Oh sorry, I have 6 text Views in the layout that matches this class.  They are all set to Visibility "gone" and I would like the one that corresponds to the item in the spinner to be set to visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have 6 text Views in the layout that matches this class. They are
>   all set to Visibility "gone" and I would like the one that corresponds
>   to the item in the spinner to be set to visible.

So this shouldn't be tricky. So you have implemented listener and make desired action.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
   String val = someFunction();
   if (val.equals("somevalue")) {
      textView.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
   }
}
```

Comment: Hey, I don't get how that would work.  The buttons are in the same layout as the content View of the class that the spinner is contained.   So there is no need to open a new class/activity

Comment: @Thomas so move setVisibity into onItemSelected method.